# How do I format output with specific width?

Tags: c++

[image]

Yeah so I guess the question is self evident from the image,I want the output text to be right below its category(eg. ID, name etc.)
  Here is the code snippet:

```
 FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Records.txt","r");
    cout<<"Category     ID     Name     Author     Quantity     Price     Rack\n\n";
    while(fread(&b,sizeof(b),1,fp)==1){
        cout<<b.category<<"     "<<b.id<<"     "<<b.name<<"     "<<b.author<<"     "<<b.quantity<<"     "<<b.price<<"     "<<b.rackno;      
        cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

Now I know I can use gotoxy() but its non standard and also not included in my header files.

Where "b" is object of class BOOK
Thank YOU!

Comment: Use `std::setw() ` to control output fields length.

Comment: why am i being downvoted?? for not rote learning every available function in c++?

Comment: You are downvoted for lacking of research before asking here.

Comment: I still dont understand how I can use setw to count spaces from the start rather than being alternate to whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Use setw() function to set the field widths.
Please follow the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/)

Comment: hello, can you  please help me know how do I left orient using setw?? It just right orients it and this link is quite confusing http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/left/

Comment: Just use the function and see what it does.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I did, and it is left oriented with one extra space:(